# CPP Debugger hits breakpoints but wrong source file mapping leads to many 'unable to resolve non-existing file' popups

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug a windows app that was compiled on Linux (WSL).

When I run the debugger it stops at breakpoints but due the source file path (as it was when it was compiled) is now wrong, so it doesn't show me the file or the line about to be executed, can't hover over variables to see their values, etc.

But if I set sourceFileMap to map the non-existing path to the correct path on windows, then all my breakpoints stop working!

[image]

How do I get around this?

---

EDIT:

Since posting this I ended up debugging a Linux build in the WSL via the Remote Explorer in VS Code successfully.

However I ***need*** to debug a Windows build now and I'm running into the same issue again!

Comment: fix the problem in your launch.json, and compile and debug the program on the same platform

Comment: The debugger works perfectly, except it provides vs code with the wrong paths. The problem could be solved with a simple string substitution. Obviously if I recompiled it on Windows that would get around the problem... but I would like a solution to this problem, not a method for avoiding it.